Why is bers' Beltrami differential harmonic?
I am reading the book "An introduction to Teihmuller spaces" by Y. Imayoshi and M. Taniguchi. In chapter 6, p153, when constructing a local inverse of Bers' Embedding, Bers' Beltrami differential constructed from a holomorphic quadratic differential is introduced.
In particular, let $H$ be the lower half-plane and $\Gamma$ be a Fuchsian group. For any holomorphic quadratic differential $\varphi\in A_2(H^*,\Gamma)$, the Bers' Beltrami differential $\mu_\varphi\in B(H,\Gamma)$ is defined as
$$
\mu_\varphi(z)=-2(\operatorname{Im}z)^2\varphi(\bar{z}), z\in H.
$$
The authors says it is a harmonic $(-1, 1)$ form with respect to the Laplace-Beltrami operator induced by the Poincare metric.
Question: Why is bers' Beltrami differential harmonic with respect to the Laplace-Beltrami operator?
The Laplace-Beltrami operator induced by poincare metric is $\Delta_H=4y^2(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}})$. But I can not see $\Delta_H(\mu_\varphi)=0$.
